# how to inject an html element with angular directives using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ng-app

I want to inject one HTML element which has been announced with angular directives. With jquery. but the application is not working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>test angular</title>
    </head>
<body>
<div id ="header" ng-app="loginApp"></div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#header").load("header.html");
  var app=angular.module("loginApp",[]);
  app.controller("loginCtrl",function(){
    $scope.data="mydata";
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the header.html is :

```
<div  ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    {{data}}
</div>
```

but there is no result also no error messages:

[image]

Comment: anyone who knows why this is not worked ,but when we use ng-include it is worked?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive for that:

```
<div  ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks~ i have studied and one more is ng-include should use as "<div ng-include src=" ' header.html' "> </div>

Comment: @vincent Oh yes, sorry, made a typo